# What is a typical fuel temperature entering the burner for different mission flight points of a civil aircraft?

Tags: fuel, fuel-systems, temperature, combustion, ignition

Is there a target regarding the fuel temperature that enters the turbine engine's combustion chamber and if so does it change with different operation flight points in civil aircraft applications?

Is there an online source you can suggest so that I get a better understanding of the fuel temperature variation in a turbine engine, and specifically what is its condition before entering the aircraft's burner?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you asking about piston or turbine engines?

Comment: Yeah i am sorry i did not clarify. I am talking about turbine engines.

Comment: The fuel is pretty warm, being heated by engine oil through a heat exchanger, but I can't remember if the fuel/oil coolers use thermostatic control to regulate the fuel temperature.  Do some searching around "fuel/oil cooler temperature control", or "thermostatic control" etc.